# What determines "effective cohort level"?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, class-feature, animal-companions

I'm making a Lion Shaman Druid and was interested in picking up a [Dragonne](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/dragonne/) as my [Monstrous Companion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/monstrous-companion/) at higher levels. A Dragonne is a 9 HD / CR 7 magical beast. What is its effective Cohort level?

I'm confused because looking at the chart a [hippocampus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/hippocampus/) is Cohort level 5 but 2 HD / CR 1.

Dragonne Description says :

> A character with the Leadership feat can take a dragonne as a cohort. Such characters must have an effective leadership level of 10th. Most dragonne cohorts gain levels in barbarian, fighter, or ranger.

Comment: You may want to include that one sticking point is that the dragonne description says, "A character with the Leadership feat can take a dragonne as a cohort. Such characters must have an effective leadership level of 10th," as that *sentence* makes no sense. (What the heck's a dude's *effective leadership level*?)

Comment: I believe it's calculated under the leadrship feat. I think Monstrous Companion came out after they printed dragonne and leadership.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I think you just answered my question lol

Comment: That certainly wasn't my intent! Really, the phrase *leadership level* appears in neither the feat [Leadership](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/leadership/) nor the feat [Monstrous Companion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/monstrous-companion/). It's as if someone wrote, "Such characters must have a *baaaarf* of 10th." Quick! Look at your character sheet! What's your *baaaarf?* `:-)`

Comment: maybe they're talking about leadership score?

Comment: Its a little of both, check my answer.

Comment: *If* that's what's meant then the dragonne is one of the game's better deals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The feat allows you to combine Leadership with animal companions

**Effective cohort level** is used to define the level of your **Monster Cohorts** ([Leadership](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/leadership)) and here it helps to calculate your *druid level* on the [Animal Companion table](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/classes/druid.html#animal-companions-184) for monster cohorts. This effectively reduces your druid level for the purposes of calculating feats, skills, bonus tricks and special abilities of your companion. This is explained under the feat [Monstrous Companion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/monstrous-companion/) (published on [Cohorts&Companions Player Companion](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9e1c?Pathfinder-Player-Companion-Cohorts-Companions)):

> Benefit(s): You can select a magical beast as a cohort in place of your animal companion class feature. Table: Effective Cohort Level **determines the effective cohort level for your monstrous companion based on your effective druid level**.

In other words, those companions are stronger than standard companions (animals), and to balance that out, they gain fewer benefits from your effective druid levels. Keep in mind that non-druids can take this feat (rangers, cavaliers, hunters, etc), so *effective druid level* is that class's level as a druid, which may or may not be equal to their class levels (rangers are level -3 for instance).

To help explain it, this is the text from the book (page 9) right before *Monstrous Companion*:

> Many classes grant characters access to animal companions. When they reach 7th level such characters can also acquire a cohort through the Leadership feat. This may lead to a single character having both an animal companion and a cohort, which can significantly slow down gameplay and cause the character to be less important than the allies at her side. **The Monstrous Companion feat allows a character to combine a monster cohort and an animal companion**, gaining benefits over either without having to keep track of both.

### Monster Cohorts

Not many people know, but the GM may allow a character with [Leadership](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/leadership) to take [Monster Cohorts](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/monster-cohorts/) (Bestiary, page 316). But this reduces the cohort's *effective cohort level*. Meaning that a *Ghoul* cohort (level 5 on the table) is harder to upgrade than a human npc, which would start with 5 class levels instead of none.

Monster cohorts can take one class level per level difference between your *Cohort Level* and the companion's *Effective Cohort Level*. And allowing the character to take a monstrous companion *and* an animal companion could easily unbalance the game, so the feat allows you to combine both into a single creature with class levels and animal companion bonuses.

### Dragonnes

As explained in the bestiary entry for [Dragonnes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/dragonne/) (bestiary 3, p. 104):

> A character with the Leadership feat can take a dragonne as a cohort. **Such characters must have an effective leadership level of 10th.** Most dragonne cohorts gain levels in barbarian, fighter, or ranger.

So, dragonnes are level 10. Meaning that you must have a *Leadership Score* of 14+, and it would have to be a 17th level druid to be able to keep one as both your cohort and your companion, as illustrated under [Monstrous Companion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/monstrous-companion/):

[image]

And for every *effective druid level* above 17th, your dragonne would gain 1 class level on the [Animal Companion table](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/classes/druid.html#animal-companions-184):

> If the magical beast’s effective cohort level is lower than what is allowed by your effective druid level, the cohort gains class levels equal to the difference. **A cohort with 1 class level gains the link and share spells abilities of an animal companio**n. A cohort with 3 class levels gains the evasion animal companion ability. A cohort with 6 class levels gains the devotion animal companion ability. If the class feature you use as a prerequisite for this feat does not grant one of those abilities (such as a cavalier’s mount, which does not gain share spells), your monstrous mount also does not gain the ability. The magical beast does not gain any abilities not listed here.

### Alright, but what's the difference?

**Leadership** will allow you to take a dragonne as cohort, but you must have a *Leadership Score* of 14 to have a level 0 dragonne. This can be obtained at 14th level by a druid with +0 charisma, maybe earlier, maybe later, depends on your score really. A 17th level druid could have a dragonne with 2 fighter levels, for instance.

**Monstrous Companion** is an alternative, and you can't have both. A dragonne companion can be taken by a 17th level druid, and would have an effective *animal companion* level of 0, gaining one animal companion level per druid level above 17th.

If instead of a dragonne (10th), this 17th level druid takes a pegasus (6th), this pegasus would gain 6 class levels with Leadership, or 4 animal companion levels with Monstrous Companion.

But keep in mind that the GM has the final say on whether Leadership is allowed in his game. A druid that takes Leadership will have two "pets" to control, for a total of three characters. While Monstrous Companion is easier to balance out, since its a single creature.

Comment: so at what level can I take a dragonne as a Cohort with this feat if I'm pure druid?

Comment: The other two points are nice but Monster Cohorts is the answer. Thnak you!

Comment: So, essentially, the term *leadership level* is pretty much by implication the same thing as *effective cohort level*, and that sentence from the dragonne description could've instead said, "Such characters must be able to have a cohort with an effective level of 10th." Is that accurate?

Comment: @HeyICanChan exactly. A 10th level npc is worth the same as a creature with *effective cohort level* of 10.

Comment: I tried to be as clear as possible, considering this information is scattered between 3 books. Suggestions and improvements are welcome.

Comment: I get that level 10 NPCs and creatures that possess an effective cohort level of 10 are equals. I'm totally on board with *that.* I'm just struggling with *A character that has the Leadership feat must have an effective leadership level of 10th to pick the dragonne* becoming *A dragonne's effective cohort level is 10th* when the latter is ***so much clearer*** than the former! It's like someone ran it through the *Google RPG Translator* or something. (I am also reminded of [this Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/RoboRosewater?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor).)

Comment: Monstrous Companion is indeed weaker than Leadership. But since most GMs will ban leadership without blinking, they may consider Monstrous Companion valid.

Comment: Um. Seriously, even the *PRD* version of the *Bestiary 3* description of the [dragonne](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary3/dragonne.html#dragonne) says, "Such characters must have an effective leadership *level* of 10th" (emphasis mine). (Had it said leadership *score*, I might've taken a shot at answering this question! `:-)`)

Comment: Yeah, my math was correct the first time. It says level, not score. So its the *level* of this cohort. A 6th level cohort could be a pegasus, a ghoul (fighter 1) or a human (fighter 6).

Comment: Does the Dragonne still gain the STR/DEX natural armor and feats from a 17th or a 10th level druid?

Comment: @VoromirKadien neither. The druid must be 17th level to get a dragonne as a level 0 companion, each additional level it gains one companion level. At druid 20, the dragonne has 3 levels as companion. This feat is known to not scale well with high *effective cohort level* companions, and its usually better (read: combat stats-wise) to have an animal companion like a tiger than a magical beast.

Comment: The point is to gain non-combat related abilities that those creatures might have. Take a look at a [kirin](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/kirin/), which has an *effective cohort level* of 13th, and thus impossible for druids.

Comment: Which is kind of interesting, because they are listed on the feat as options: *In addition to the magical beasts listed in Table: Bestial Cohorts above, this feat can be used to gain an ahuizotl, aranea, blink dog, dragon horse, dragonne, giant eagle, giant owl, giant vulture, griffon, kirin, leucrotta, manticore, pegasus, sea cat, shedu, sleipnir, worg, or xanthos.* (Sleipnirs are 16th)

Comment: With leadership couldn't the pegasus gain up to 9 class levels under leadership? You can have a cohort 2 levels below your level.

Comment: even young dragons are CR +8 Cohort effective level

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72562/discussion-between-voromir-kadien-and-shadowkras).

Comment: I cannot help but to notice that the post did not actually seem to answer the question: If a Hippocampus has a Cohort Level of 5, but is 2 HD, a Hippogriff has a Cohort Level of 6 but is 3 HD, while a Worg has a Cohort Level of 9, but is 4 HD. How is this determined? Also, "Effective Leadership Level" of a character with the Leadership Feat doesn't even seem to be a rules term; I believe it is meant to say that the cohort has an effective cohort level of 10. Or something. But that still gives no hint of how that is determined.

Comment: @Luckmann it seems the OP disagreed, as he marked the answer as answered. Regardless, "effective leadership level" is not a defined game term, but its what the rules say about creatures like the Dragonne, as that was quoted directly from the book. As I did not invent that wording, you may complain directly at Paizo. As for "how" it is determined, I did link to the table from the bestiary, but I cannot answer what the designers were thinking when they created that table, you will have to ask them directly.

Comment: If I had to guess, HD has nothing to do with this, as it is a bad measurement of the overall power and/or usefulness of a creature. But that's just my guess.

Comment: My comment was in no way intended to criticize the answer as such - it's a great answer and I myself found it very helpful. I just felt it was worth pointing out, and that there are circumstances that contribute to the difficulty in giving a clear and concise answer to the actual, specific, question. It appears to me, as you likewise suggest, that "cohort level" is determined seemingly arbitrarily by the writers, which is frustrating as a GM, especially when dealing with creatures of varying HD or templates.